# Date.getTime is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, date

In a function I have the line:

```
const currentTime = new Date.getTime();
```

The code compiles just fine.
Also, [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) displays neither warnings or
errors.
But when I run the code, I get an alert box giving the confusing
message `Date.getTime is not a constructor`.

*What is wrong here?*

[image: Error message: 'Date.getTime is not a constructor']

---

I have noticed that there is no error if I don't call the function
that contains the line above.

The following Stack Snippet reproduces the error.

```js
function rightNow() {
  const currentTime = new Date.getTime();
  return currentTime;
}
console.log(rightNow().toString());
// ^^ No error if I comment out the previous line! ^^
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It's `(new Date).getTime()` or `new Date().getTime()` - or just use `Date.now()`. What you've written is `new (Date.getTime)`.

Comment: The compiler doesn't throw an error because it's grammatically correct: the *new* keyword followed by a function call is fine. However, not all functions are constructors. BTW, `new Date().getTime()` is functionally identical to `Date.now()`, which is less to type. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. Quick fix

Just add parentheses immediately after `new Date` :

```
const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
```

#### 2. Explanation

##### `Date.getTime is not a constructor`

If the compiler were a thinking human being, it could respond to the
snippet

```
new Date.getTime();
```

by saying *Aha! I think I get what you mean: there is a class named
`Date.getTime` and now you want to call the default constructor
to create a new object: `new Date.getTime()`, right?*
*Well, sorry, but I could not find any such constructor.*

And I can hear you – the programmer – screaming *No!! That's **not**
what I meant! (Stupid ✴!☠#@☠$% compiler!)*

After you have chilled down enough to restore a reasonably normal
blood pressure, you might – patiently – try something like:

*Mr Compiler, we obviously got off on the wrong foot – I never
meant to hurt your feelings.
What I want is: please create a new `Date` object, and then call
the `getTime()` method on that newly created object.*
*Look, let me put it as follows, to see if you better understand my
point of view?*

```
const currentTime = (new Date).getTime();
```

##### `Missing '()' invoking a constructor  new-parens`

[image: To invoke the default constructor, '()' is missing.]

The response by Mr Compiler :

```
Missing '()' invoking a constructor  new-parens
```

Or – in a more human langage.
*OK! So you want to create a new `Date` object?*
*And on that object you want to `.getTime()`?*
*That's fine. – Except that you forgot to tell me **which**
constructor you want me to use. Is it the default constructor?
Or some other constructor?

Since you didn't tell me, I will assume you
want me to use the **default** constructor.*
*But would you consider being more explicit the next time you ask me
to do something like this?*
*That way I would not have to make an educated guess on what you mean.*

After resigning with a sigh, you – the programmer – try again:

```
const currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
```

##### Finally – no complaints from Mr Compiler!

This time around, Mr Compiler responds with silence, which is good
news!
– Responding with silence shows that Mr Compiler is in his very best
mood.

Still, you are a *human* and not a compiler, so you could *imagine*
Mr Compiler saying:
*OK. So `(new Date()).getTime()` means you want to create a new
`Date` object using the default constructor, and then call
`getTime()` on that object. It's all fine. I have no complaints.*

But since you are a very *sensitive* human, you cannot help yourself
asking:

*Good! I'm glad we finally agree on this. But is there something
still on your mind? Forgive me for asking.*

Upon which you *imagine* Mr Compiler responding:

*No no. Your code makes sense. It's OK. It really is.*
*But well, since you keep nagging me – writing `(new Date())` is fine.
There is nothing wrong with it. But you don't **need** the surrounding
parentheses. Once you write `new Date()` then I understand that you
want to create a Date object, even if you then call a method on that
object.*

– *I am not **stupid** you know!*

#### Epilogue

As a general rule, runtime errors – like in this question – are often
much harder to understand and debug than compiler errors and
warnings.
This is when a Stack Overflow question-and-answer might be helpful.
As pointed out in the comments, a shorter alternative to
`new Date().getTime()` is the plain and simple `Date.now()`.

Here is a Stack Snippet without the error.

```js
function rightNow() {
  const currentTime = Date.now();
  return currentTime;
}
console.log(rightNow().toString());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Reference

- [Date() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

Comment: nicely explained  

Comment: "*The response by Mr Compiler: `Missing '()' invoking a constructor  new-parens`*" - that's not Mr Compiler, that's Mr Linter trying to interrupt your conversation with the compiler.

Comment: _that's Mr Linter trying to interrupt your conversation with the compiler_
Thanks! You are right of course. Still, I might not change my answer accordingly, as I don't want to complicate the story more than necessary ... Or maybe I will ... Thanks anyway.